# Is this set-up PCI DSS compliant?

Tags: stripe-payments, pci-compliance, pci-dss

Setup:

1. `Mobile` uses [Stripe](http://www.stripe.com) to get credit card token.
2. `Mobile` sends token to `Server 1`.
3. `Server 1` gets credit card details using the token.
4. Instantly, the `Server 1` encrypts the details and sends it to a PCI DSS compliance `Server 2` via an SSL connection.

Does `Server 1` has to be PCI DSS compliant?

Answer (score 3):

Your set up won't work. You cannot get raw credit card details from a Stripe token. Even if you could, you'd still be handling sensitive information and would have to be PCI compliant.

For your flow to work you'd have to send the raw details to `Server 1`, which puts you in the SAQ D category of PCI compliance (the harshest one): https://stripe.com/docs/security#validating-pci-compliance

Comment: How to get credit card details https://stripe.com/docs/api/issuing/cards/retrieve_details

Comment: That's for virtual cards created via Stripe Issuing only, it won't work on real cards.

Comment: Even if you _can_ get the card data from the Stripe token, `Server 1` has access to the raw data and thus is in SAQ D level PCI scope.